# Zisserman Lecture and $x_{MLE}$

Tags: calculus, statistics, probability-distributions, optimization

In the Zisserman Lecture below

http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/lectures/est/lect34.pdf

page 36, he derives $x_{MLE}$ for Gaussian sensor fusion.

[image]

There are two noisy measurements $z_1$ and $z_2$ and assuming both describe the same point but with different variances, author comes up with the derivation above.

I could not understand how he could jump to that $x_{MLE}$ that quickly, which is basically the $x$ that would turn everything between brackets to zero, and along with it everything else except for the const part in the formula. I believe Zisserman obtained this by taking the derivative of everything in the $[]^2$, set the result to zero and solve. Would this be the correct assumption?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You would be correct. MLE's maximize the log-likelihood. Since the function is quadratic in x, it will have a single maximum that can be found by setting the derivative to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See @Eupraxis1981 - "the function is quadratic in x, it will have a single maximum that can be found by setting the derivative to zero".

A multivariate normal based derivation for sensor fusion can be found [here](http://sayilarvekuramlar.blogspot.co.uk/2015/12/istatistik-ve-veri-analizi.html).